# Combining Scriptaculous and jQuery in a Rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scriptaculous

I've got the following situation

- A rails application that makes use of rjs / Scriptaculous to offer AJAX functionality
- Lot of nice javascript written using jQuery (for a separate application)

I want to combine the two and use my jQuery based functionality in my Rails application, but I'm worried about jQuery and Scriptaculous clashing (they both define the $() function, etc).

What is my easiest option to bring the two together? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then use jQuery instead of $ to refer to jQuery. e.g.,

```
jQuery('div.foo').doSomething()
```

If you need to adapt jQuery code that uses $, you can surround it with this:

```
(function($) {
...your code here...
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's `jQuery.noConflict()`.

You can call it standalone like this:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery('div').hide();
```

Or you can assign it to another variable of your choosing:

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('div').hide();
```

Or you can keep using jQuery's `$` function inside a block like this:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

 // Put all your code in your document ready area
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // Do jQuery stuff using $
   $("div").hide();
 });
// Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
$('someid').hide();
```

For more information, see [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) in the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[jRails](http://ennerchi.com/projects/jrails) is a drop-in replacement for scriptaculous/prototype in Rails using the jQuery library, it does exactly what you're looking for.